# To normalise MongoDB/Mongoose, in order to simplify GraphQL Schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql

Assume a Seller schema with over 60+ embedded fields representing 1:1 and 1:M relationships and mix of embedded documents and document references, e.g "director", "addresses" and "bankAccounts". We are definitely not storing anything big that would exceed 16MB document limit). You essentially have a typical, best practice, de-normalised NoSQL schema design.

A friend is suggesting that we should break out previously embedded fields of say "director", "addresses" and "bankAccounts" into their own schema and collections. Each has an added "sellerId" field to point to its creating owner/Seller.

My friend's argument is that by doing this our GraphQL type and input schema definitions become easier to define and manage - considering 60+ fields for Seller? So instead of creating a single, massive 60+ field "type" and "input types" definition in our GraphQL Schema, he can now break out "directors", "addresses" and "bankAccounts" into their own types and input definitions

Q1. Is there any valid logic in this? To normalise the MongoDB to simplify the GraphQL schema type and input handling?

Q2. Assuming we did break out those aforementioned, previously embedded fields, which are mostly stale and infrequently queried data anyway, is it realllllly that bad to do so and to normalise in MongoDB?

Yes, I know if you normalise too much, why don't you use an RDB/SQL?? I guess because having JavaScript knowledge, working with JSON and Mongoose ORM, having limited resources, makes it an attractable data store.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying data source should not drive your schema design -- the needs of the clients consuming your API should.

That aside, whether you're querying an embedded document or using `populate`/`$lookup` to pull in referenced documents, the data returned will be in the same shape, so it's unclear how this difference has anything to do with your GraphQL schema. What's more, the shape of the data returned by your data source does *not* need to match your schema. Even if you have a flat data structure like:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "addressLine: "...",
  "city": "...",
  "state": "...",
  "zipCode": "...",
}
```

Your GraphQL type can look like this:

```
type User {
  name: String
  address: Address
}
```

Similarly, your data source could return nested data and your schema could be more flat. In both cases, you just need to provide the appropriate resolvers (like a resolver for the address field in the example above).

There may be performance and cost concerns that should factor into your decision to normalize or denormalize the data -- or whether you should drop MongoDB altogether. But your schema should not be a factor at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll provide more context in separate answer.

Comment: @JohnPham You should edit your question instead of posting an answer. Regardless, I'm not sure what that adds to my response. Again, the point of my answer is that however your data is organized in MongoDB is irrelevant to your schema. There's nothing about one approach or the other that will make your GraphQL schema "more modular" or "easier to manage".